# Most efficient/Safest method of creating new instance of random class

Tags: java

I'm writing a 2d java game and I'm randomly spawning in creatures as the map scrolls. However, I need to randomly choose a creature type - which means I need to randomly choose a class from a list and create a new instance of it.

My entity classes currently take a constructor argument (a reference to the game) but this can be moved if it makes this process easier.

I was originally going to use an enum that defined the entity types along with "handler classes" but the enum system doesn't work well for me at this point because there's too much logic for different properties of different entities.

Comment: Have a class with a factory method and send a parameter that tells what to create. Note that all these *random* classes should have a common parent class or interface in order to ease the code. Refer to this in [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: To follow up Luiggi's comment, the class with the factory method would decide which monster to spawn and construct an instance of that class. The classes could be very different but should have a common interface or abstract class.

Comment: Ya, I've used this same pattern before but not for random stuff - that makes sense. I guess I'll just use a random number based on the count of classes added to the list

Comment: Can you please show the enum that you used, so it's easier to see where it stopped working well?

Comment: The enum works fine, it's just that the logic I was originally using the enum to determine became too variable - it's different in too many situations to keep that logic in the enum. There's barely any point in the enum after removing the logic.

Answer (score 2):

Create an enum for your monsters, and use `Math.random()` to pick one:

```
public enum Monster {
    AcidBlob,
    Orc,
    Etc
}

Monster m = Monsters.values[Math.random() * Monsters.values().length];
```

You can add methods and fields to your enum just like a regular class.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you wish, use a list of class names, and use Class.forName(className).newInstance() to create an instance.  You don't need to cast the result to the actual class name, just the common superclass for all your monsters.

```
String randomMonsterName = listOfMonsterNames[randomIndex];
Monster newMonster = (Monster) (Class.forName(randomMonsterName).newInstance());
```

It does, of course, require that your monsters can be constructed with just the default constructor.  (You can do otherwise but it gets messier.)